# Merge multiple files into a single stream in Python

Tags: python, file, mmap

I have a dozen of files that I would like to present to the user as a single read only file like object. I do not want to load them into memory at once, nor merge them in the filesystem. I would like something like a `itertools.chain` of `mmap.mmap` but present the API of a file like object (i.e. with the file methods like read, etc). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fileinput` module here to read through multiple files.

Lets say for example you want to read two files `new.txt` and `IQ.txt`.

```
for line in fileinput.input(["C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\new.txt","C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\IQ.txt"]):
print line,
```

In nutshell you provide a `list` of files you want to read and do it.

Comment: I do not thinkg that will work. The FileInput object does not implement common file methods such as read)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question. I want that it present the API of a file like object, for example the method `read`

Comment: @Hernan so this gives you an object wherein you can read line by line file by file?

Comment: @Hernan: "...The function returns an iterator which returns individual lines from the text files being processed." from the link: http://pymotw.com/2/fileinput/
and i guess it is doing exactly what you want: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fileinput.py

Comment: @namit Thanks but actually is not doing what I want. You answering on the assumption that people always want to read lines from a file, but as I said in my question I need at least the `read` method (and that read `n` bytes). I guess the file input can be modified for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have had some success with the [`SplitFileReader` function from here](https://pypi.org/project/split-file-reader/):

```py
from split_file_reader import SplitFileReader

filepaths = [...]

with SplitFileReader(filepaths, mode="rb") as fin:
    fin.read(...)
```

The [builtin `fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html?highlight=fileinput) can only be used for text files, because it does not implement the read function.

The [`splitfile` function from here](https://pypi.org/project/splitfile/) probably works, too, but it has its own convention of how the partial files must be named, and does not simply accept a list of paths.

I am surprised I could not find a builtin function for such a fundamental task, or a package developed by a bigger community.